# How to connect on Nucleo with GDB?

Tags: c, gdb, embedded, stm32, nucleo

I am using `arm-none-eabi` toolchain to create binary file for Nucleo which I then flash to the Nucleo using the USB virtual storage device it provides.

I am compiling the program with `-ggdb`. But how could I possibly connect to the nucleo and execute breakpoints on it? I can't even imagine how could it work, but I'm complete beginner.

Can I connect? How?

Comment: I recommend visiting [this website](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/). It'll lead you through the steps of setting up a complete working project environment. A simplier approach, if you want to "just get going", you can go and install [SW4STM32](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/sw4stm32.html). It's almost the same as the first one in a single, ready to use package.

In general yes, you can build, run and fully debug your program on microcontrollers through hardware debuggers such as ST-Link (already on your Nucleo), J-Link and other.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can connect, at least from a Linux host. I never tried from Windows system. Use [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org/) to open a debug port and connect gdb (used arm-none-eabi-gdb) to this port with ["gdb extended-remote"](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Server.html) command. I am using this method from Linux host PC to connect to a custom board based on STM32L4 series for debugging and collecting log messages. Nucleo boards are also using the same series of STM controller.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth there's a free IDE call EMBlocks that I've used in the past.  I think the new version is called EMBitz https://www.embitz.org/ 
I've used it to both flash the STM32 Nucleo boards as well as debug the flashed image file.

A quick search also turns up this website that seems to indicate you can use GDB with the stlink utility. https://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/6189

Comment: I need to avoid any IDE's unfortunatelly.

Comment: @TomášZato are you on a windows machine?  Apparently you can connect using the gdbserver in the stlink utility http://www.emb4fun.de/archive/stlink/

Comment: I actually ideally need to find and document Windows and Linux compatible toolchain. But I'm trying to ask questions step by step when I get stuck. Thanks for the link :)